# Flutter Firebase Iterator Error with FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, iterator

Running my App on Android and iOS I get the Error shown below. What I want to do, give every Data that get's added a Author, the Author should be the Mail Adress the User Registers with, so by Inviting other Users get Access to this Data.

Another Problem is that in Line 302 the String "user" is unused.
Do i really need to use this String?

**Error**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<FirebaseUser>#7f7ed):
The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: iterator

The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser> 
lib/…/MealPlan/mealTile.dart:92
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/Widgets/whenAndWhatToEat.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/global.dart';
import 'package:status_alert/status_alert.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class MealTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final MealsAndWhen mealsAndWhen;
  MealTile({this.mealsAndWhen});

  @override
  MealTileState createState() {
    return MealTileState();
  }
}

class MealTileState extends State<MealTile> {
  String id;
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  String mail;
  List<String> authors = [];

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future pickDate() async {
    DateTime datepick = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: new DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 0)),
        lastDate: new DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 365)));
    if (datepick != null)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = datepick;
      });
  }

  Future<String> inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return user != null ? user.uid : null;
  }

  Future<String> inputDataMail() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return user != null ? user.email : null;
  }

  String userId;

  void _getUserId() {
    inputData().then((value) => setState(() {
          userId = value;
        }));
  }

  String currentMail;

  void _getMail(doc) {
    inputDataMail().then((value) => setState(() {
          currentMail = value;
        }));
  }

  /*void _getAuthors(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    authors = [];
    //if (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null) {
      authors = List.from(doc.data['Authors']);
      print(doc.data['authors']);
      //authors.insert(0, currentMail);
    //}
  }*/

  Widget buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    DateTime now = doc.data['Date'].toDate();
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    _getUserId();
    _getMail(doc);
    if (doc.data['Authors'] != null) {
      //_getAuthors(doc);
      //print('Current mail: ' + currentMail + authors.toString() + doc.data['Author'] + doc.data['Meal']);
    }

    if (now.day == DateTime.now().day) { // If the Date of the meal is today
      deleteData(doc, false); // Delete it!
    }
    // You could also change ".day" to ".hour".
    // Example: if (now.day == DateTime.now().day && now.hour == DateTime.hour())
    // So, if a meal is set for 2PM, it will delete at 2PM

    return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot != null) {
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: currentMail == doc.data['Author'] || // If the current mail is the author
                      List.from(doc.data['Authors']).contains(currentMail) // Or if the current mail is part of the authors
                  ? Column( // then if  true, show a Column
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Meal:',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${doc.data['Meal']}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Text(
                          'When:',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => updateData(doc),
                              color: lightBlueColor,
                              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              tooltip: 'Update Date',
                            ),
                            Text(
                              formatted,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                            FlatButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              onPressed: () => deleteData(doc, true),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(12)),
                              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Delete',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white)),
                                Icon(Icons.delete_forever, color: Colors.white),
                              ]),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                            FlatButton(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              onPressed: () => [
                                showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return Dialog(
                                        child: invite(doc),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(12)),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    })
                              ],
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(12)),
                              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Invite',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white)),
                                Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white),
                              ]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : Text(''), // if false, show an empty text widget
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: lightBlueColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              ),
            );
          }
          else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          /*Navigator.pop(context);
          return HomePage();*/
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: darkGreyColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 220),
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db
                .collection('mealList')
                .orderBy('Date', descending: false) // Order by Date, not descending
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents
                        .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
                        .toList());
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /*share(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final dynamic date = timeago.format(doc['Date'].toDate());

    Share.share(
      "${doc['Meal']} - $date",
      subject: doc['Meal'],
      sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
    );
  }*/

  Widget invite(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
          Center(
              child: Text(
            "Invite someone by mail",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 24,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                labelText: 'Enter the email address'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter an email address';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onSaved: (value) => mail = value,
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                saveInviteToFirestore(doc, mail);
              }
            },
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
            child: Text("Save"),
            color: redColor,
            textColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getCurrentUser() async {
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) => value.uid);
  }

  void saveInviteToFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc, String email) async {
    final String user = await getCurrentUser();
    var list = List<String>();
    list.add(email);

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('mealList')
        .document(doc.documentID)
        .updateData({"Authors": FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)});
    //setState(() => id = doc.documentID);
    StatusAlert.show(
      context,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      title: 'Added',
      subtitle: 'You have Added your and the Date to your List',
      configuration: IconConfiguration(icon: Icons.done),
    );
    //Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void deleteData(DocumentSnapshot doc, bool showMessage) async {
    await db.collection('mealList').document(doc.documentID).delete();
    setState(() => id = null);
    if (showMessage) {
      StatusAlert.show(
        context,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        title: 'Deleted',
        subtitle: 'You have Deleted your Meal',
        configuration: IconConfiguration(icon: Icons.delete),
      );
    }
  }

  void updateData(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    await pickDate();
    await db
        .collection('mealList')
        .document(doc.documentID)
        .updateData({'Date': selectedDate});
    StatusAlert.show(
      context,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      title: 'Updated',
      subtitle: 'You have updated your Meal Date',
      configuration: IconConfiguration(icon: Icons.done),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `firebase_auth` are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebase_auth: ^0.16.0